# How can we get more moderator flags?

Tags: stack-egg

Is there a way to receive more moderator flags, or are we capped at the maximum of 1 flag? The description reads "You have a limited amount of flags", but that seems to imply there are more than a single flag available.

Is there a way to get more flags?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In my experience, you get one flag when starting public beta and another flag after graduating.

I do not know of any way to get more than those two flags.

Comment: Yup! Per the help page: *At birth, in private beta, your pet Site does not have any moderator flags. When it reaches public beta and when it graduates, it receives one flag each as a present for achieving an important milestone in its life.*